# HiddenField set from JavaScript not persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a UserControl with a HiddenField, UpLoad control, and DropDownList that are referenced on an ASPX page in a SharePoint Solution. The markup for the controls is:

```
<ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDownDocumentType" runat="server" Width="135px" DataSourceID="DataSourceDocumentType" DataKeyFields="Id" ValueField="Id" TextField="Name" AutoPostBack="False" ClientEvents-SelectionChanged="WebDropDownDocumentType_SelectionChanged">
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDocumentType" runat="server" />
<ig:WebUpload ID="WebUploadSupportingDocuments" runat="server" ProgressUrl="/WebUploadStatusHandler.ashx" Height="100px" MaxSimultaneousFilesUploads="1" Width="100px" OnUploadFinished="WebUploadSupportingDocuments_UploadFinished" AutoStartUpload="True" OnUploadStarting="WebUploadSupportingDocuments_UploadStarting" >
```

When the selected index is changed for the DropDownList a javascript function is called to set the HiddenField value. I also added an alert to validate that the HiddenField contains the value and it does display the expected value. This is the function:

```
function WebDropDownDocumentType_SelectionChanged(sender, e) {
        var wddObject = sender, 
        selectedIndex = wddObject.get_selectedItemIndex(), value;
        value = wddObject.get_items().getItem(selectedIndex).get_value();
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnDocumentType.ClientID %>').value = value;       
        alert(document.getElementById('<%=hdnDocumentType.ClientID %>').value);
    }
```

After selecting an item from the DropDownList I see the function call and verify that the value in the alert is correct. I then click the button to select a file to upload and the UploadFinished event fires. When I set a breakpoint in the UploadFinished event and check the value for the HiddenField instead of it being the expected value it is an empty string.

```
string sDocumentType = hdnDocumentType.Value;
```

If I do not close the page and upload another file it then has the value for the selected item in the dropdown. If I then select another item from the dropdown and upload another file it has the previous selection and then on the next file upload the next selection. So it is an empty string the first time and then one selection behind for each file I upload going forward.

I am not sure why the value is not persisting and am looking for suggestions on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: IIRC it depends on when in the page lifecycle you invoke `hdnDocumentType.Value`. Does `Request.Form[hdnDocumentType.UniqueID]` give you the right value?

Comment: something else I just noticed: If I do not close the page and upload another file it then has the value for the selected item in the dropdown. If I then select another item from the dropdown and upload another file it has the previous selection and then on the next file upload the next selection. So it is an empty string the first time and then one selection behind for each file I upload going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem can be upload component. It can use iframe to upload files to server (this is how for example Async File Upload from Ajax Control Toolkit and some other upload component work). This can be the cause of the problem why hidden field is empty (because request was done from iframe). If this is your case then you need to handle client side event which will notify you when upload is completed (of course if this component support them) and perform postback manually (or ajax request) to perform required actions.